# Fit image inside png Image (Frame)

Tags: android, imageview

I have a png image which I want to use as a frame for images in `ImageView`. [image: Sorry, it's white that's why invisible]
Sorry, it's white that's why invisible

[image: Like this but with sides curved]
Like this but with sides curved

What is the solution?
I've tried by converting png to patch 9, setting background of parent and source of image view, but none worked. Image doesn't fit inside.

Comment: try this example code on github..... https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it using `PorterDuff`. Designed an extra image just with curved border and applied `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER` inside `setImageResource` of Custom Image View.

Here is the overriden function

```
@Override
public void setImageResource(int resId) {
    Bitmap rawBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), resId);
    Bitmap rawMask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.image_frame_arc_filled);
    Bitmap rawBorderMask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.image_frame_arc);

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rawBmp, rawBmp.getWidth(), rawBmp.getHeight(), true);
    Bitmap mask = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rawMask, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), true);
    Bitmap borderMask = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rawBorderMask, mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), true);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);


    Paint maskPaint = new Paint();
    maskPaint.setXfermode(
            new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, maskPaint);

    maskPaint = new Paint();
    maskPaint.setXfermode(
            new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER));
    canvas.drawBitmap(borderMask, 0, 0, maskPaint);

    this.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```